# Excel product function in CPLEX

Tags: excel, cplex

I'm looking for a function in CPLEX like the "Product' function in excel. It will give me product of all elements of an array.
have anybody ever seen something like it?

Answer (score 0):

in OPL you could write

```
float a[i in 1..10]=i;
float b[i in 1..10]=i+1;
float ab[i in 1..10]=a[i]*a[i];

execute
{
 writeln(ab);
}
```

that gives

```
[1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81 100]
```

regards